# Google Analytics no recoge datos de mi sitio web

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

Recientemente he configurado Google Analytics en mi sitio web desarrollado en Wordpress (www.seresendesarrollo.com). Lamentablemente, por alguna razón que desconozco, no logro que el sistema de Google recoja datos. Sé que la configuración la he hecho correctamente porque he configurado muchos sitios web que funcionaron y siguen funcionado con Google Analytics perfectamente.

He probado insertando el Global Site Tag (gtag.js), tanto al principio como al final de la etiqueta , pero el problema persiste. Si inspecciono el código fuente de cualquiera de las páginas de mi sitio web, el Global Site Tag aparece correctamente.

¿Podrán orientarme sobre qué puede estar pasando?

Gracias.

EDICIÓN: estuve haciendo unas pruebas y me di cuenta de que Google Analytics no recibe (o descarta) la conexiones realizadas desde Firefox (el navegador que utilizo). Ingresé a mi web desde Chrome (Desktop Linux y Mobile Android) y el sistema registró perfectamente las visitas.

¿Es normal esto?

Comment: Te sale algún error en la consola del navegador cuando cargas la página?

Comment: No, no me aparece ningún error.

Comment: Entré a tu sitio y veo que las cookies de GA se setean. Y uso Firefox.

Comment: Qué raro porque no veo ninguna visita realizada mediante Firefox. Sólo figuran Chrome, Android Webview y Safari.

Comment: A veces los bloqueadores de publicidad afectan la recolección de datos de Google Analytics, ya que bloquean el script necesario.